# 'Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The console in google chrome is saying 'Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined' when attempting to show list items in console. I am very new to jquery I would appreciate some help for this.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<style>
      ul li {
    color:red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li>hello</li>
</ul>


 <script>
 var lis = jquery('ul li');
 console.log(lis);  

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `$()` notation?

Answer (score 1):

It is `jQuery` and not `jquery`. Change:

```
jquery('ul li');
```

To:

```
jQuery('ul li');
```